# Get python to end the program in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am creating a game style program and are looking for a command that will just end the program at a certain point. There are no syntax errors and it all correctly indented in the idle.

I want this command to execute after the 'YOU DIED GAME OVER' bit of the if statment.
I tried to look for anything online but i couldn't find any hints. 
Code below

```
buy2a = input ('Type Y to drink the strange liquid and type N not to')
if buy2a == 'Y' or buy2a == 'y':
    chance2a = 2 #random.randint(1,4)
    if chance2a == '2' or chance2a == '4' :
      print ('You start to choke and you black out')
      print ('YOU DIED')
      print ('GAME OVER')
      # >Thing im looking for goes here!<#
else :
    print ('You feel strange')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('You blackout but wake up several hours later')
    time.sleep(1)
    health = 20
    print ('You feel a lot better and now have ' + str(health) + ' health')

else :
    print ('You pass on the offer with a weak reason and head off in a hurry')
print ('You enter the next town on weiry feet')
```

Comment: You should `break` out

Comment: There are errors in the code.

Comment: Having to call `exit()` in your code to terminate the program on normal behaviour might indicate that you did not structured it well.

Answer (score 4):

Use (this is standard practice for exiting):

```
import sys  # At the start of file.
sys.exit()  # When you want to exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

Built-in `exit()` function will work. Another option is to use [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=exit#sys.exit).

Both `sys.exit` and `exit` raise the same exception `SystemExit`. The difference is in convenience: you need to import `sys` module every time you want to use `sys.exit` and `exit` is the part of [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) that's imported during the initialization.

Comment: Pretty sure the `exit` is only intended for interactive use

Answer (score 0):

You can also raise the exception directly

```
raise SystemExit()
```

Comment: This is not recommended: you're directly raising a builtin exception instead of the preferable (and overwrittable) `sys.exit` wrapper. Also the brackets are not necessary.

Comment: @AlexThornton: can you point me to anything explaining why `sys.exit` is better than `raise SystemExit`?